# error C2440: 'argument' : cannot convert from 'System::Object ^' to 'int'

Tags: visual-studio-2005, c++-cli

this is my code:

```
for (q = 0; q < Rows; q++)
{
    for (r = 0; r < Columns; r++)
    {
        Array1[q, r] = combo1->Items[r];
        Array2[q, r] = combo2->Items[r];
    }
}
```

I want to add items in arrays from combo boxes but I am getting the error:

> error C2440: 'argument' : cannot convert from 'System::Object ^' to 'int'

this is the code which is adding items in combo

```
            for (int m = 0; m < Rows; m++)
            {
                array<String^> ^b = Aray1[m]->Split(gcnew array<Char> { ',' });
                for each (String ^Column in b)
                {
                    Combo1->Items->Add(Column);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using C++/CLI.

Judging by the error it looks like the `Array1` elements are typed to `int` and the combo box contains values wrapped in an `ObjecT^`.  If the value is truly just an `int` being wrapped in an `Object^` then you just need to unbox

```
Array1[q,r] = safe_cast<int>(combo1->Items[r]); 
Array2[q,r] = safe_cast<int>(combo2->Items[r]);
```

This will fall if the `Object^` is actually wrapping another type besides `int`

Comment: now i am getting this error"Specified cast is not valid." with code Array1[q,r] = safe_cast<int>(combo1->Items[r]);

Comment: @m,qayyum then it's likely the items in the combo are not wrapped `int` values but are a different type which must be converted to an `int`.  Likely a `string`.  What is the type of the objects in the combo?

Comment: string type items are in combo

Comment: @m.qayyum have you verified that by calling `combo1->Items[r]->GetType()`?

Comment: @m.qayyum right but have you verified via the code snippet in my comment that they are actually typed to `int`?